# Debian SSH two step auth

Tags: ssh, security, debian

How can I setup two step auth like two passwords ?

On Debian 7 with latest SSH. And without using Google auth or something simillar.

Comment: Just as a point of security:  Having two passwords is functionally identical to having one password as long as the two passwords combined.  That is, unless you expose information about whether either password is individually right.  In that case the two password approach is worse than one long password.

Comment: And what about two long alphanum passwords with symbols will it be better ? Or password and code from SMS using own systems and not Google auth or something ?

Comment: Two passwords are not functionally better than one password that consists of those two passwords concatenated.  Instead, they are often worse.  That is the only point I was making.  I have different comments about other "two factor" illusions, but those are out of context here.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want this for? Normal ssh key verification really should be enough. Anyway, if you really want to do this, one way would be to force the user to enter a password upon connection. There is a [nice answer](https://serverfault.com/a/93809/155817) on Server Fault explaining this.

The basic approach is to run a script upon connection that prompts your user for a different password. You can do this using the `ForceCommand` directive in your `ssh_config` file. As explained in `man sshd_config`:

```
  ForceCommand
         Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand,
         ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if
         present.  The command is invoked by using the user's login shell
         with the -c option.  This applies to shell, command, or subsystem
         execution.  It is most useful inside a Match block.  The command
         originally supplied by the client is available in the
         SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable.  Specifying a command
         of “internal-sftp” will force the use of an in-process sftp
         server that requires no support files when used with
         ChrootDirectory.
```

So, if you point this to a script that asks for a password and kills the connection if it doesn't get the right one, you will have set up a two-step verification.